# Efficient data saving, like system (example)

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm building a school project with several class mates. We've ran into a (minor) problem.

There will be a 'forum' where classmates can post questions and where others can give answers/replies to.

We're working with an ASP.NET Core application (web api). So, here's the case: we want classmates to be able to like questions, answers and replies.

I've built some models, what we could do is make a 'like' table for each section (questions, answers, replies). But I think that's a little inefficient.

```
public class Question
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Now my question is, what would be the most efficient way to save these likes? I've built a like model already, but I'm not sure what would be the best.

```
public class Like
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public User User { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried somethings like adding an `ICollection<Like>` to the Question, Answer and Comment model, but can't figure out on how to use this.

I hope someone has a solution.

Comment: Your question model will also need a collection of answers and a collection of comments, and if you want to enable comments on answers, those will need a collection of comments too. I am assuming your question class also has a Body. You could use an enum TypeOfPost in your Like, specifying if it is a like for a question, answer or comment and then storing the Id of the corresponding post.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to write out an answer to your solution? @AsheraH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines should get you started.
Adopt your Question, Answer and Comment classes:

```
public class Question
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers {get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments {get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments {get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Then create an enum with the possible types of posts:

```
public enum TypeOfPost
{
Question,
Answer,
Comment
}
```

Use this enum in your Like class:

```
public class Like
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public User User { get; set; }
   public TypeOfPost PostType { get; set; }
   public Guid LikedPostId { get; set; }
}
```